# how can I create a new variable by comparing different rows that have the variable values in common?

Tags: r

When working with a data set like the following:

```
program <- c("Miami", "Miami", "Miami", "Orlando", "Orlando", "Tampa")
student <- c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Brandon", "Brandon", "Michael")
assessment_date <- c("2019-07-01", "2019-07-27", "2019-08-02", "2019-07-25", "2019-08-05", "2019-07-25")
score <- c(2.3, 3.5, 2.8, 5.6, 5, 5.5)
```

From this dataset I will like to group_by the rows by program and student, to then pull the minimum date from that group_by and establish a new column call Pre_Score.

An example of the output I hope it looks like this:

```
names(df) <- c("Program", "Student", "Pre Score")
df[1, ] <- c("Miami", "Mark", 2.3)
```

I hope this make sense. Any help would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group_by` function from `dplyr` is perfect for this.

```
program <- c("Miami", "Miami", "Miami", "Orlando", "Orlando", "Tampa")
student <- c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Brandon", "Brandon", "Michael")
assessment_date <- c("2019-07-01", "2019-07-27", "2019-08-02", "2019-07-25", "2019-08-05", "2019-07-25")
score <- c(2.3, 3.5, 2.8, 5.6, 5, 5.5)

df <- data.frame(program,student, assessment_date = as.Date(assessment_date), score)
```

Make sure that `assessment_date` is in the `Date` format using `as.Date`. Using `filter` within `group_by` ensures that we will only get the first date for each student x program combination.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(program, student) %>%
  filter(assessment_date == min(assessment_date)) %>%
  select(program,student, pre_score = score)
```

Results

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   program, student [3]
  program student pre_score
  <fct>   <fct>       <dbl>
1 Miami   Mark          2.3
2 Orlando Brandon       5.6
3 Tampa   Michael       5.5
```

Comment: you can also use `mutate(Pre_Score = min(assessment_date))` to create the new column Albatross needs

Comment: true, but I think the OP is more interested in the score than the date. I've edited the answer above to rename the score column and drop assessment_date

Comment: ahh, you are right. I've misread the actual requirements. Thanks for highlighting that

Comment: Thank you for the lesson! @m.evans. I did not know that I could use a function different than summarise after using group_by.